# Can we configure Email Sender Address in mailing on publication basis?

Tags: outbound-email

How can we configure Email Sender Address in mailing on publication basis? As I am able to configure the email sender address in mailing on CME level by changing in outboundemail.xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to define on a Publication level. You can define a default for new Mailings in OutboundEmail.xml (DefaultSenderAddress), but it is a system-wide default and each Mailing can still override that.

Comment: Thank's Peter for your confirmation.